# AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE trigger violates not-null constant

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers, sql-insert, postgresql-9.5

In a word game SQLite database I would like to store short words and words with the seldom `Q` letter in *clear text* (to be able to list them in the app).

Otherwise I would like to store only an MD5 hash of a word (so that the app database is not easily stolen).

At the backend side I use PostgreSQL 9.5 and have prepared the stored function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hash_word(in_word varchar(255))
        RETURNS varchar(32) AS
$func$
        SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(in_word) > 3 AND in_word !~ 'Q'
        THEN UPPER(MD5(in_word)) ELSE in_word END
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Which seems to work fine:

```
# SELECT hash_word('ABC');
 hash_word
-----------
 ABC
(1 row)

# SELECT hash_word('ABCDE');
            hash_word
----------------------------------
 2ECDDE3959051D913F61B14579EA136D
(1 row)

# SELECT hash_word('SQUAD');
 hash_word
-----------
 SQUAD
(1 row)
```

Then I create a table to store uppercased english words and their hashed values and the INSERT OR UPDATE trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION english_nouns_trigger()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
        DELETE FROM english_nouns WHERE word = NEW.word;

        INSERT INTO english_nouns(word, hashed)
        VALUES (NEW.word, hash_word(new.word));

        RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

DROP table IF EXISTS english_nouns;
CREATE TABLE english_nouns (
        word varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (word ~ '^[A-Z]{2,}$' AND
                word !~ 'JQ' AND
                word !~ 'QG' AND
                word !~ 'QK' AND
                word !~ 'QY' AND -- impossible english bigrams
                word !~ 'QZ' AND
                word !~ 'WQ' AND
                word !~ 'WZ'),
        hashed varchar(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER english_nouns_trigger
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON english_nouns
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE english_nouns_trigger();
```

Unfortunately, when trying to insert test values, I get the error:

```
# INSERT INTO english_nouns (word) VALUES ('ABC'), ('ABCDE'), ('SQUAD');

ERROR:  null value in column "hashed" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (ABC, null).
```

**UPDATE:**

When I change `AFTER` to `BEFORE` as suggested by Richard (thank you!) -

```
CREATE TRIGGER english_nouns_trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON english_nouns
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE english_nouns_trigger();
```

then I unfortunately get another error:

```
# INSERT INTO english_nouns (word) VALUES ('ABC'), ('ABCDE'), ('QI');

ERROR:  stack depth limit exceeded
HINT:  Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "DELETE FROM english_nouns
        WHERE word = NEW.word"
PL/pgSQL function english_nouns_trigger() line 3 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO english_nouns(word, hashed) 
        VALUES (NEW.word, hash_word(new.word))"
PL/pgSQL function english_nouns_trigger() line 6 at SQL statement
SQL statement "INSERT INTO english_nouns(word, hashed) 
        VALUES (NEW.word, hash_word(new.word))"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to change the data before it is inserted? Use a before trigger, not an after trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 rows in your table:

```
word varchar(255) 
hashed varchar(32) NOT NULL
```

You are only inserting a value for word. So essentially what you are really inserting is:

```
INSERT INTO english_nouns (word, hashed) VALUES ('ABC', NULL), ('ABCDE', NULL), ('SQUAD', NULL);
```

Not inserting a value for hashed, with a NOT NULL restriction will raise that error.

You'll need to insert some value for hashed:

```
INSERT INTO english_nouns (word, hashed) VALUES ('ABC', somevalue), ('ABCDE', somevalue), ('SQUAD', somevalue);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the following `BEFORE` trigger seems to work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hash_word(in_word varchar(255))
        RETURNS varchar(32) AS
$func$
        SELECT CASE WHEN LENGTH(in_word) > 3 AND in_word !~ 'Q' 
        THEN UPPER( MD5(in_word) ) ELSE in_word END
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION english_nouns_trigger()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS
$func$
BEGIN
        NEW.hashed := hash_word(NEW.word);

        RETURN NEW;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


DROP table IF EXISTS english_nouns;
CREATE TABLE english_nouns (
        word varchar(255) PRIMARY KEY CHECK (word ~ '^[A-Z]{2,}$' AND
                word !~ 'JQ' AND 
                word !~ 'QG' AND 
                word !~ 'QK' AND 
                word !~ 'QY' AND 
                word !~ 'QZ' AND 
                word !~ 'WQ' AND 
                word !~ 'WZ'),
        hashed varchar(32) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER english_nouns_trigger 
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON english_nouns
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE english_nouns_trigger();
```

Demonstration `INSERT`:

```
# INSERT INTO english_nouns (word) VALUES ('ABC'), ('ABCDE'), ('QI');
INSERT 0 3

# TABLE english_nouns;
 word  |              hashed              
-------+----------------------------------
 ABC   | ABC
 ABCDE | 2ECDDE3959051D913F61B14579EA136D
 QI    | QI
(3 rows)
```

Demonstration `UPDATE`:

```
# UPDATE english_nouns SET word = 'ABCDEF' WHERE word = 'ABCDE';
UPDATE 1

# TABLE english_nouns;
  word  |              hashed              
--------+----------------------------------
 ABC    | ABC
 QI     | QI
 ABCDEF | 8827A41122A5028B9808C7BF84B9FCF6
(3 rows)
```